# React Native TouchableHighlight image not working on Android phones

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I created a custom component to have a stack of images on top of each other and when you click on an image, it goes to the back and the next one is visible and so on.

The following code is working on an Android Emulator (Pixel 4 Tiramusi) and on the web but it doesn't work when testing the app with expo go on a OnePlus 8 and Samsung Galaxy.
We can see the animation (Highlight of the image) but nothing happens.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet, View, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

var getRandomRotation = function(index)
{
  return (index) * 8 + 'deg';
}

export default class ImageStack extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  
    this.state = {
      imagesList: [
        { source: require('../assets/cards_400_400/wolf_400_400.png'), zIndex: 0 },
        { source: require('../assets/cards_400_400/villager_400_400.png'), zIndex: 1 },
        { source: require('../assets/cards_400_400/witch_400_400.png'), zIndex: 2 },
        // Add more images to the list as needed
      ],
    };
  }

  moveToBack = (index) => {
    let counter = 0;
    const updatedImagesList = this.state.imagesList.map((img, idx) => {
      counter++;
      if (idx === index) {
        return { ...img, zIndex: 0 };
      } else {
        return { ...img, zIndex: counter };
      }
    });
  
    let newImagesList = [];
    updatedImagesList.sort((a,b) => a.zIndex > b.zIndex ? 1 : -1).map((image) => newImagesList.push(image));
    this.setState({ imagesList: newImagesList });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.imagesList.map((image, index) => (
          <TouchableHighlight
            key={"touchable-image-" + index}
            style={{ zIndex: image.zIndex }}
            onPress={() => this.moveToBack(index)}
          >
            <Image
              key={"image-" + index}
              source={image.source}
              style={{
                ...styles.cardImage,
                transform: [{ rotate: getRandomRotation(index) }],
              }}
              resizeMode="stretch"
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardImage: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6,
    borderRadius: 10,
    transform: [{ rotate: '12deg'}],
    margin: 20,
    position: "absolute",
    left: -(Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6) / 2 - 20,
    top: -(Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6) / 2 - 20
  }
});
```